# How to display term in archive page?

Tags: posts, taxonomy, archives

I want to display 'state' in my custom post type 'job' Archive page. Now my archive page only have title and excerpt. Can you tell me how to modify this 'content-job.php file?

p.s. My post type is 'job', taxonomy is 'state'. California or New York will be term in the 'state' taxonomy. 'underscorefoundation' is themename.

```
<?php
/**
 * @package underscoresfoundation
 */
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h1>' ); ?>

        <?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : ?>
        <div class="entry-meta">
            <?php underscoresfoundation_posted_on(); ?>
             <?php the_terms( $post_id, $state, $before, $sep, $after ); ?> 
        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
<?php if ( is_search() || is_archive()|| is_category() || is_tag() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
        <div class="entry-summary">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
        <?php else : ?>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php
            /* translators: %s: Name of current post */
            the_content( sprintf(
                __( 'Continue reading %s <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'underscoresfoundation' ),
                the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">"', '"</span>', false )
            ) );
        ?>

        <?php
            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'underscoresfoundation' ),
                'after'  => '</div>',
            ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <?php endif; ?>

</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

Comment: `$state` should be `'state'` - the former is an undefined variable with no value, the latter is a string with value "state".

Answer (score 0):

Use [wp_get_object_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms) function to get any taxonomy you want, category, tag, state, etc.

For example:

```
$terms = wp_get_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 'state');
$state = array_pop($terms);
echo $state->name;
```

This function is returning array of terms, so in case you only have one state, it will return array of one item in it.